# Сжатие журнала БД

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день, со временем журнал БД сильно увеличился. Как мне его сжать? Модель восстановления полная. Интересует метод с возможностью восстановиться на любой момент момент времени и без.
Знаю метод:

```
USE MyBase;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyBase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyBase_Log, 1);
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyBase SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO
```

есть ли еще варианты?

Comment: а как у вас устроена стратегия резервного копирования - как часто делается резервная копия (`backup`) БД и журнала?

Comment: Две разностных копии каждый будний день и в сб, и полная в вс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас полная модель восстановления и вы не делаете бэкап журнала транзакций? От этого у вас и разрастается журнал. Вам необходимо добавить бэкап журнала транзакций и тогда вы сможете сразу после его выполнения выполнить операцию DBCC SHRINKFILE без изменения модели восстановления БД, так же рекомендую не урезать размер файла до 1 мб, а хотя бы указать 1ГБ(но это все зависит от размера вашей базы).